# Generate Sequence number for each line at the end .. modified t he post can someone help&suggest on this

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have got this query

```
sed '/./=' abc.txt| sed '/./N; s/\n/, /' >> as.dat


source file has 3 rows like below
a
b
c
```

When use the following command it gives me result like this

```
Output 

    1 a
    2 b 
    3 c
```

but I would like to have output of the command like this

```
Output 

    a 1 
    b 2 
    c 3
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts. Your sed command doesn't make much sense, are you missing a `|`? Also, please[edit] and show us an example of your actual input file. Will there always be a single word per line? No spaces?

Comment: This seems to be easier with `awk`. Is `sed` a requirement or just an idea?

Comment: Do you just want to swap the two fields around? I'd use awk for that: `awk '{print $2,$1}'`

Comment: Thanks for your time ..I dont want to swap i want generate sequence number at the end of each line for example i have just given a single character since my file is huge ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix have these wonderful little tools called `cut` and `paste`.  The `cut` tool will extract a set of columns from its input while the `paste` tool inserts columns. We will be using these.

I'm not going to care about your pipeline too much (right now, but see the end of this answer), I'm just concerned with the problem of switching the columns around.

Let's say I have this data in a file called `cols.txt`:

```
$ cat cols.txt
1 a
2 b
3 c

$ paste -d ' ' cols.txt cols.txt
1 a 1 a
2 b 2 b
3 c 3 c
```

The `paste` utility usually inserts a tab between columns, but here we have told it to insert a space instead (`-d ' '`).

Then it's just a matter of extracting the second and third columns out of the output from `paste` with `cut`:

```
$ paste -d ' ' cols.txt cols.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

We've told `cut` that we have spaces as "field separators" (`-d ' '`, it otherwise expects tabs) and that we would like to have fields 2 and 3 (`-f 2,3`), please. (Unfortunately, just asking `cut` for columns "`2,1`" in the original input will *not* swap the columns.)

So in the end there is really no need for messy regular expression magic here.

Back to your pipeline. Let's scrap that.  It seem as if you would want to insert the line number to each line.  There's another Unix tool for that called `nl` ("number lines"):

```
$ nl abc.txt
     1  a
     2  b
     3  c
```

You got line numbers for each non-empty line by default, preceeded by some spaces for padding and delimited from the original line by a tab character. Would you want to number empty lines too, use

```
$ nl -b a abc.txt
```

As far as I know, you can't get `nl` to put the line numbers to the right of the line, but that's not a problem because we have a solution that will swap two columns of input:

```
$ paste <(nl abc.txt) <(nl abc.txt) | cut -f 2,3
a            1
b            2
c            3
```

We've done away with specifying delimiters here. `nl` will insert spaces followed by a line number and a tab at the beginning of each line. `paste` inserts a tab between its columns, and `cut` cuts on tabs, so it'll work.

If you want a single space between you columns (there's now a tab and some spaces), add `| tr -s '\t' ' '` to the command.  This will change ("transliterate") all tabs to spaces, and will "squeeze" (`-s`) the resulting consecutive spaces into one space.

If you want a comma and a space instead, use `| tr '\t ' ', '` instead:

```
$ paste  <(nl abc.txt) <(nl abc.txt) | cut -f 2,3 | tr -s '\t ' ', '
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
```

This works on file with multiple words on each line, but will fail on files containing tab characters:

```
$ cat abc.txt    # no tabs in this file though
a text     there is a
b goes     hole in my
c here     pants

$ paste  <(nl abc.txt) <(nl abc.txt) | cut -f 2,3
a text     there is a        1
b goes     hole in my        2
c here     pants             3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/./=' | sed '/./{N; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/;}'
```

But `awk` would be more straighforward:

```
awk '/./ {$0 = $0 " " NR}; {print}'
```

It seems strange that you would only number the lines that contain at least one character. If that was not your intention, then you can change it to:

```
sed = | sed 'N; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
awk '{print $0, NR}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions..I have updated my posts a bit ...I was not clear at the first place , sorry about that ...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do your task would be to use the `nl` command with `-nln` option. This numbers the lines from a file. For example..

`echo -e "a\nb\nc\n" | nl -nln -`

would produce:

```
 1  a
 2  b
 3  c
```

Now all remains is to move numbers to the right of the words. This can be done using `sed` as follows:

`sed 's/^\([^ \t]*\)[ \t]*\([^ \t].*\)$/\2 \1/g'`

What this does is finds the first word in a line (To find the first word we have to include only those characters other than space and tab. This is done using `[^ \t]`) and remembers it as `\1` and the part of line following the whitespaces as `\2` and replaces the line with `\2 \1`.

So the final command would be

`cat filename | nl -nln - | sed 's/^\([^ \t]*\)[ \t]*\([^ \t].*\)$/\2 \1/g'`